# Solr - Solrconfig.xml variable is not parsing using <xi:include href=""

Tags: xml, solr, solrconfig

Im trying to parse solr variable to include differnet database settings depending on a variable.

`-Dsolr.host=dev2.cr9`

In solr log I got this exception

> Exception during parsing file: solrconfig.xml:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: solrres:/solrconfig.xml; lineNumber: 91;
>
> columnNumber: 123; An include with href 'file:///var/lib/solr/conf/database.dih.${solr.host}.xml'failed,​ and no fallback element was found.

How can I parse solr variable href -> `using <xi:include href=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it in a different way.

The following sample attempts to include `database.dih.prod.cr.xml` If it doesn't exist or can't be loaded then `database.dih.dev.cr.xml` will be used instead.

**solrconfig.xml**

```
 <!--- including database config -->
    <xi:include href="file:///var/lib/solr/conf/database.dih.prod.cr.xml"  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
       <xi:fallback>
          <xi:include href="file:///var/lib/solr/conf/database.dih.dev.cr.xml" />
      </xi:fallback>
   </xi:include>
```

**database.dih.web0.psnt.xml**

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
             <lst name="datasource">
             <str name="driver">org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</str>
             <str name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306database_name</str>
             <str name="user">userName</str>
             <str name="password">password</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```